# Parsing Based on the xml file order using xsl

Tags: xslt

To translate one xml format to other xml format i am using xsl.I have written few templates in my xsl file.
I am facing some issue wit the translation order as below.

My xsl Template:

```
 <xsl:template match="rhs" name="rhsTemplate">

                <xsl:if test="brl:retract | retract!= ''">
                    <xsl:for-each select="brl:retract | retract">
                        <xsl:element name="freeForm">
                            <xsl:element name="text">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:if>


    <xsl:if test="brl:tryCatchBlock | tryCatchBlock!= ''">
                        <xsl:if test="brl:tryCatchBlock/brl:try | tryCatchBlock/try!= ''">
                            <xsl:element name="freeForm">
                                <xsl:element name="text">
                                    <xsl:text>try{</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:element>


</xsl:template>
```

when i send the following xml file as an input i am getting the output which is not desired one.

```
                               <rhs>  
                                <tryCatchBlock identifier="8" order="0">
                                <try>
                                </try>
                                </tryCatchBlock>
                <retract identifier="1" order="1">
                    <variableName>$Event1</variableName>
                </retract>
```

Output:

```
<freeForm>
<text>retract($Event1);</text>
</freeForm>
<freeForm>
<text>try{</text>
</freeForm>
```

Desired Output:

```
<freeForm>
<text>try{</text>
</freeForm>
<freeForm>
<text>retract($Event1);</text>
</freeForm>
```

My requirment is irrespective of conditions inside the xsl template the translation needs to happen based on the input xml file order.Here in my xsl template i  have if condition for retract before the trycatch if condition.hence the translation for "retract" is happening first then its translating the trycatch tag though my input xml contains trycatch tag prior to retract tag.

Please provide me some pointers to do the translation based on the input xml content order.
But the desired output is as below(As per the input xml order).

Comment: I haven't studied your problem in detail, but at a glance, you've got `brl:retract | retract!= ''`.. should this be `brl:retract | brl:retract!= ''`? i.e., the namespace isn't specified on the second reference to the `retract` element.

Comment: yeah it is brl:retract | retract!= '' only.sometimes xml file may comes with namespace and sometimes without namespace.to handle this i have added both senarios.

Answer (score 0):

Your output is in that order because that's how your template is outputting it; it's specifically outputting any 'retract' blocks, then outputting any try/catch blocks.

I'd recommend a slight redesign:

```
<xsl:template match="rhs" name="rhsTemplate">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="retract">
  <xsl:element name="freeForm">
    <xsl:element name="text">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tryCatchBlock">
  <xsl:element name="freeForm">
    <xsl:element name="text">
      <xsl:text>try{</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

The first template might be superfluous; XSLT does this by default anyway, but given that it's named, I thought there might be a reason for that.

Obviously you'll need to expand this to accommodate namespace issues; to be honest, I'm not clear on where the text `retract(` is coming from, but hopefully this solution should give you some pointers.